# How do I create a one page survey with inputs

Tags: python, user-interface, frontend

I want to create a one page survey online that will present a question page that looks like this:

[image: form with several varying basic inputs]

... and will then store the answers in the program for me to review later.

I have tried a basic input output version but would prefer all questions on a single page.

Comment: You can use Tkinter...  `Spinbox`, `Entry`, `Label` and `Radiobutton`.

Answer (score 1):

I am at work and bored so i programmed it for you:

```
from tkinter import *
import json

window = Tk()
window.geometry('550x350')

label1=Label(text='UNIVERSITY STUDENT SURVEY')
label1.pack()

firstname_label=Label(window,text='First Name')
firstname_label.place(x=0,y=25)
name_input=Text(window,height=1,width=40)
name_input.place(x=70,y=25)

date_label=Label(window,text='Date')
date_label.place(x=400,y=25)
date_input=Text(window,height=1,width=10)
date_input.place(x=450,y=25)


sleep_label=Label(window,text='What hours do you normally sleep?')
sleep_label.place(x=0,y=24*2)
bedtime_label=Label(window,text='Bedtime')
bedtime_label.place(x=20,y=25*3)
choices = []
for i in range(7,12):
    choices.append(f'{i}.00pm')
for i in range(5):
    choices.append(f'{i}.00am')
bedtimevariable = StringVar(window)
bedtimevariable.set('10.00pm')
bedtime_menu = OptionMenu(window, bedtimevariable, *choices)
bedtime_menu.place(x=70,y=25*3-5)

wakeup_label=Label(window,text='Wake Up Time')
wakeup_label.place(x=170,y=25*3)
choices = []
for i in range(4,13):
    choices.append(f'{i}.00am')
wakeupvariable = StringVar(window)
wakeupvariable.set('8.00am')
wakeup_menu = OptionMenu(window, wakeupvariable, *choices)
wakeup_menu.place(x=250,y=25*3-5)

exercise_label=Label(window,text='Do you exercise?')
exercise_label.place(x=0,y=25*4)
choices = ['YES','NO']
exercisevariable= StringVar(window)
exercisevariable.set('YES')
exercise_menu = OptionMenu(window, exercisevariable, *choices)
exercise_menu.place(x=100,y=25*4-2)

epriority_label=Label(window,text='What priority is exercise?')
epriority_label.place(x=0,y=25*5)
evar=IntVar()
epriority_rbtn1=Radiobutton(window, text="High", variable=evar, value=1)
epriority_rbtn2=Radiobutton(window, text="Medium", variable=evar, value=2)
epriority_rbtn3=Radiobutton(window, text="Low", variable=evar, value=3)
epriority_rbtn1.place(x=150,y=25*5)
epriority_rbtn2.place(x=250,y=25*5)
epriority_rbtn3.place(x=350,y=25*5)

smoke_label=Label(window,text='Do you smoke?')
smoke_label.place(x=0,y=25*6)
choices = ['YES','NO']
smokevariable= StringVar(window)
smokevariable.set('YES')
smoke_menu = OptionMenu(window, smokevariable, *choices)
smoke_menu.place(x=100,y=25*6-2)

smokeyear_Label=Label(window,text='If yes, around what year did you start smoking?')
smokeyear_Label.place(x=0,y=25*7)
smokeyear_input=Text(window,height=1,width=10)
smokeyear_input.place(x=260,y=25*7)

smokeday_Label=Label(window,text='If yes, how many a day?')
smokeday_Label.place(x=0,y=25*8)
svar=IntVar()
smokeday_rbtn1=Radiobutton(window, text="10", variable=svar, value=1)
smokeday_rbtn2=Radiobutton(window, text="11-20", variable=svar, value=2)
smokeday_rbtn3=Radiobutton(window, text="20-40", variable=svar, value=3)
smokeday_rbtn4=Radiobutton(window, text="40+", variable=svar, value=4)
smokeday_rbtn1.place(x=150,y=25*8)
smokeday_rbtn2.place(x=250,y=25*8)
smokeday_rbtn3.place(x=350,y=25*8)
smokeday_rbtn4.place(x=450,y=25*8)

spriority_label=Label(window,text='If yes, what priority is smoking?')
spriority_label.place(x=0,y=25*9)
spvar=IntVar()
spriority_rbtn1=Radiobutton(window, text="High", variable=spvar, value=1)
spriority_rbtn2=Radiobutton(window, text="Medium", variable=spvar, value=2)
spriority_rbtn3=Radiobutton(window, text="Low", variable=spvar, value=3)
spriority_rbtn1.place(x=170,y=25*9)
spriority_rbtn2.place(x=270,y=25*9)
spriority_rbtn3.place(x=370,y=25*9)

smokeplace_Label=Label(window,text='If yes, where do you normally smoke?')
smokeplace_Label.place(x=0,y=25*10)
smokeplace_input=Text(window,height=1,width=10)
smokeplace_input.place(x=210,y=25*10)

privacy_Label=Label(window,font=("", 7),text='Thank you for taking part in this survey. Your information will be kept private under university privacy rules.')
privacy_Label.place(x=50,y=25*11)

def submit():
    data={
        'firstname':name_input.get("1.0","end-1c"),
        'date':date_input.get("1.0","end-1c"),
        'bedtime':bedtimevariable.get(),
        'wakeuptime':wakeupvariable.get(),
        'exercise':exercisevariable.get(),
        'exercisepriority':'',
        'smoke':smokevariable.get(),
        'smokeyear':smokeyear_input.get("1.0","end-1c"),
        'smokeday':'',
        'smokepriority':'',
        'smokeplace':smokeplace_input.get("1.0","end-1c")
        }
    exec(f'data["exercisepriority"]=epriority_rbtn{evar.get()}["text"]')
    exec(f'data["smokeday"]=smokeday_rbtn{evar.get()}["text"]')
    exec(f'data["smokepriority"]=spriority_rbtn{evar.get()}["text"]')
    print(data)
    with open('data.data','w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data))
    '''
    If you want to load the data
    with open('data.data','r') as f:
        data=json.loads(f.read())
    '''
    
    

submit_btn=Button(window,text='Submit',command=submit)
submit_btn.place(x=250,y=25*12)







window.mainloop()
```

Comment: That looks great. Forgive me for being so new to Python but I'm not sure how to access the data - I saw the code at the bottom in '''  ''' but not sure what it means. Thanks for the code though. My studying brain appreciates it.

Comment: @StarrNight the data is generated in a file called data.data

Comment: @StarryNight you can either just open the data.data file with notepad and read it yourself or access it in the code by using the code in """ """ and it saves it in the variable data.
The .data extention is just to make it look cool if you want you can replace the data.data with data.txt it really doesnt matter.
The reason i used json is because i used a dict in the data variable.
The code in """ """ basicaly just reads the file with f.read() and retuns a string and to convert it into a dict i use the func json.loads()
also i forgot if you want to change the title use window.title('title')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).